# On ios how do i save the full url to home screen?

Tags: ios, mobile-safari, mobile-device-management, safari-extensions, json

Safari iOS doesnt save the relative URL (start_url) due to / setting in the manifest json.

Is there a way to fix this so that i get the full url (not header url) that i currently have open in Safari iOS? Maybe with 3rd party tool or workaround (laptop). My added home page icon doesnt save the correct landing website otherwise!